# PySpark Remove Values Before Delimiter and Keep Duplicate Key Value Pairs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD that has some characters before a delimiter underscore ('*'). I need to go through each key and remove everything before the delimiter, including the underscore, and keep the duplicate key value pairs if there are any. I have some code that removes the duplicates, but that doesn't work. You can see how 'bin1*' and 'None_' in the second record would have the same key value and hence one gets removed after the function. I need to maintain those duplicates to later explode by the key by the value. Below is my code for the RDD and output:

## Sample of RDD

```
>>> rdd3.take(2)
[{u'bin1_11394071': 1, u'bin1_11052103': 1, u'bin1_11052101': 1}, {u'bin1_11847272': 10, u'bin1_999999': 1, u'None_11847272': 10}]
```

## Function To Remove String before the Delimiter

```
>>> rdd4 = rdd3.map(lambda x : {k.split('_')[1]:v for k,v in x.iteritems()})
>>> rdd4.take(2)
[{u'11394071': 1, u'11052101': 1, u'11052103': 1}, {u'999999': 1, u'11847272': 10}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. Define a function (this one is called `trim_prefix`) that returns a list of tuples instead of a dictionary like so:

```
def trim_prefix(x):
    l = []
    for k,v in x.iteritems():
        l.append((k.split('_')[1],v))
    return l
```

Then run your map against the function:

```
rdd4 = rdd3.map(lambda x : trim_prefix(x))
```

This results in an list of lists of tuples as opposed to a list of dictionaries:

```
rdd4.take(2)

[[(u'11394071', 1), (u'11052103', 1), (u'11052101', 1)],
[(u'11847272', 10), (u'999999', 1), (u'11847272', 10)]]
```

Comment: This is great @markwatsonatx ! Any downside to working with tuples versus a list of dictionaries? I'm still super new to both python and spark actually.

Comment: I don't think there are any downsides. You won't be able to perform look ups by key, but in your case you have duplicate keys, so dictionaries aren't really an option.